# Parse JSON in Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, jsonkit

I have this json returned from a cms and I need to break it apart and use the different values.

```
{"nodes":
     [{"node":
        {"created":"14012013165204","lastupdated":"03042013133901","type":"News"}
     }]
}
```

I use JSONKit framework and here is my code:

```
    NSString* theURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://testserver.com/content_lastupdate.json"];
    NSError* err = nil;
    NSURLResponse* response = nil;
    NSMutableURLRequest* request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
    NSURL*URL = [NSURL URLWithString:theURL];
    [request setURL:URL];
    [request setCachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData];
    [request setTimeoutInterval:30];
    NSData* data = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&err];

    NSString *output = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSDictionary *resultsDictionary = [output objectFromJSONString];

    NSLog([NSString stringWithFormat:(@"Response: %@"), output]);

    NSDictionary *nodes = [resultsDictionary objectForKey:@"nodes"];
    NSObject *node = [nodes objectForKey:@"node"];
```

I do not know how to get the next part of the results. nodes key is found but the next one is not. Any idea what basics I'm missing here?

Comment: A) Learn how to read JSON -- it's very simple.  Check out JSON.org.  B) Use NSLog.  It prints out decoded JSON objects in a JSON-like syntax (though `()` is used instead of `[]`), so you can see the structure as you "peel" each layer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"nodes" is an array. Try this one:

```
NSArray *nodes = resultsDictionary[@"nodes"];
NSDictionary *node = nodes[0];
node = node[@"node"]
```